# Communication frontend - backend, and security issue

Tags: django, security

I have a problem with security. I have backend in Django (little mechanics and webpage). On webpage I have some tiles with some content. After click on this tiles logged user (request.user) earn some points. But this adding is by url. I mean.

```
<a href='{url "path_to_view" tiles_id}'>
```

And in webpage source I can see this url and id. And someone can send this request without click or change replace tiles_id and send other. How to prevent this situation, and secure this?

Comment: use some sort of hash instead of id

Comment: but still someone can see this link and call it without click :)

Comment: i donu enough about your app but some sort of csrf protection will do , create a session when user requests tiles page and check that session to exist in the next page and destroy the session at the end of the process so he cant use it again